# text classification with SciKit-learn and a large dataset

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, scikits

First of all I started with python yesterday. I'm trying to do text classification with SciKit and a large dataset (250.000 tweets). For the algorithm, every tweet will be represented as a 4000 x 1 vector, so this means the input is 250.000 rows and 4000 columns. When i try to construct this in python, I run out of memory after 8500 tweets (when working with a list and appending it) and when I preallocate the memory I just get the error: `MemoryError` (np.zeros(4000,2500000)). Is SciKit not able to work with these large datasets \? Am I doing something wrong (as it is my second day with python)? Is there another way of representing the features so that it can fit in my memory ?

**edit**: I want the to the Bernoulli NB

**edit2**: Maybe it is possible with online learning ? read a tweet, let the model use the tweet, remove it from memory , read another, let the model learn... but I don't think Bernoulli NB allows for online learning in scikit-learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that these 4000 x 1 vectors are bag-of-words representations. If that is the case, then that 250000 by 4000 matrix has a lot of zeros, because in each tweet there are only very few words. This kind of matrices are called [sparse matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), and there are efficient ways of storing them in memory. See the [Scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) and the [SciKit documentation](http://scikits.appspot.com/sparse) for sparse matrices to get started; if you need more help after reading those links, post again.

Comment: Actually, the scikits.sparse package is irrelevant to this problem, and scikit-learn includes quite some functionality to hide the complexity of scipy.sparse from the user, esp. in the case of document classification. -1 for suggesting the OP roll their own.

Answer (score 7):

If you use scikits' vectorizers (`CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` are good as a first attempt) you get a sparse matrix representation. From the documentation:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(data_train.data)
#initialize your classifier
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning the documentation of [text feature extraction documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) that explicitly deal with sparsity issues with text data.